# Populating select menu using database elements - Python/Django/javascript/html

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

As the title suggests, I am trying to populate an HTML select menu using elements from a database. Right now, I have a set of file systems (issp's) which are associated with a set of compatible operating systems (many-to-many relationship). When a user selects an issp version from the drop-down, I want its compatible operating systems to be displayed without hardcoding a bunch of javascript arrays.

I have no problem populating my issp select menu from the database as the template is passed the full list of issp's as part of its context. However, because Django does not allow the use of python methods which take arguments, I'm having trouble populating the operating system menu.

I want to do something *like* this (though I realize it's impossible this way, I'm looking for suggestions about an alternate route):

```js
function populateSelect(select, osId) {
    $(osId).html("");
    var issp_version = $(select).val(); 
    for (i = 0; i < { issp_list.filter(issp=issp_version).os_length }; i++) {
        $(osId).append('<option value="{ issp_list.filter(issp=version).os.all()[i] }" display = ...")
```

Where osId is the id corresponding to each operating system select menu. and the function issp.os_length() is a user-defined method that just gives the length of the list of compatible operating systems.

Comment: What is `issp_list` in that JavaScript?

Comment: @DanielRoseman issp_list is the context passed in my views file. Its just a list of every available issp. I use it to populate the select menu which contains issp versions.

Comment: So you're trying to call a Python function inside your Javascript one? That can't possibly work.

Comment: Well it does work using Django's template language as long as the python method doesn't take any arguments. This is why I can populate my issp select menu. I call { issp.get_issp_display } within a Django-template for loop

Comment: No it really doesn't, and can't. The template variable is executed when the template is rendered. The JS isn't executed until the function is called (presumably in response to a DOM event). So there's absolutely no way to use a variable from JS in a template variable, and this has nothing to do with the fact that you can't pass arguments to a function call. In fact, you can, by writing a template tag or filter, and this still wouldn't work, for the reason I just mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow (sorry I've been using Django for about 2 days). You are saying I can't use template variables/methods inside Javascript, yet I have a Javascript function which populates a select menu using the Django template variable issp_list and it utilizes two of its methods AND it works. Not saying what you said is incorrect, but to say that python/django functions can't be called inside of Javascript is contrary to what I have done thus far which, as I said, has been working.

I do see what you are saying about using JS variables in Django. Just wondering how to get around this

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying you can't call a template variable dependent on a value that you get from Javascript, which you seem to understand.

Comment: And your solution, by the way, is to use Ajax to fetch a new list from the server dependent on the value of the select box.

Comment: Well I have absolutely no idea how to do this as I've been doing web development as long as I've been using Django, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction at least